# When I try to run a script on python3 I get: SyntaxError: Invalid syntax (mac)

Tags: python-3.x

when I try to run a script via terminal, this happens:

```
>>> python3 Somador.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python3 Somador.py
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The script I saved on text editor.

Comment: You need to run `python3 Somador.py` in the shell, not inside python.

Comment: You're trying to run it from Python interpreter. It should be run from the shell instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run mac OS right? So I guess there is some program named "Terminal" or "Bash shell" or something; you get what I mean. You open it up. You navigate to the folder where your program lies (using `cd`). If you just want to execute the program, type `python3 Somador.py`. If you want to execute the program interactively type `python3 -i Somador.py`. Then a *python* shell will open which is very different from the *bash* shell you opened first. A *python* shell does not know the command `python3`.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to run a Python script from inside of the Python shell, but only Python code should be run from the python shell. Run `python3 Somador.py` directly from the command line.